# jQuery Tool Tips - Like Twitter's

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

How can I make jQuery tooltips like on Twitter?

Comment: Way too broad.  At least show some code for what you've attempted.

Comment: Which tooltips are you talking about specifically? Most of the mouseovers look like they're just setting the `title` attribute of a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyTips is a good plugin to make tooltips.

http://www.mikemerritt.me/blog/jquery-plugin-tinytips-1-1/